# Using a shared library in a project and build it using Ant

Tags: android, ant

I have a project A which uses a project B as its library .What should I do in-order to create a build by using ant?I am trying to use this in my android project without using eclipse's wizard to do this for me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a target for project A that depends on project B.

```
<target name="projectB" description="Builds project B">
    <!-- all the tasks to build project B -->
    ...
</target>

<target name="projectA" depends="projectB" description="Builds project A">
    <!-- all the tasks to build project A -->
    ...
</target>
```

Comment: Thanks.what if my project B is in a repository,can I download that?

Comment: There's no specific git ant task, but you can call system commands with `exec` task http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html